# Keras ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs

Tags: python, keras, resnet

When I have already finish my function model , I can't use it the predict_classes(), and I try Sequential(layers=model.layers) to let me use predict_classes() it tell me the wrong, It's very strange

#### This is my function model

```
def resnet_v1(input_shape, depth, num_classes):

    if (depth - 2) % 6 != 0:
        raise ValueError('depth should be 6n+2 (eg: 20, 32, 44 in [a])')
    # Start model definition.
    num_filters = 16
    num_res_blocks = int((depth - 2) / 6)

    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = resnet_layer(inputs=inputs)
    # Instantiate the stack of residual units
    for stack in range(3):
        for res_block in range(num_res_blocks):
            strides = 1
            if stack > 0 and res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stack
                strides = 2  # downsample
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=x,
                             num_filters=num_filters,
                             strides=strides)
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=y,
                             num_filters=num_filters,
                             activation=None)
            if stack > 0 and res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stack
                # linear projection residual shortcut connection to match
                # changed dims
                x = resnet_layer(inputs=x,
                                 num_filters=num_filters,
                                 kernel_size=1,
                                 strides=strides,
                                 activation=None,
                                 batch_normalization=False)
            x = keras.layers.add([x, y])
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
            #x = LeakyReLU()(x) #改relu -> LeakyReLU
        num_filters *= 2

    # Add classifier on top.
    # v1 does not use BN after last shortcut connection-ReLU
    x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=8)(x)
    y = Flatten()(x)
    outputs = Dense(num_classes,
                    activation='softmax',
                    kernel_initializer='he_normal')(y)

    # Instantiate model.
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

model = resnet_v1(input_shape=input_shape, depth=depth)
model = resnet_v1((32,32,1), 26, 26)
```

It give me the Error, when I want to change function model to Sequential model
Keras ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs

Comment: when I want to change function model to Sequential model to like this Sequential(layers=model.layers), it tell me Keras ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs,
but type(model.layers) is already a list!!!  So this is my question!!

Comment: Why do you want to change this to the Sequential model? As you have discovered, this is likely not possible. The Sequential model is much more limited in what architectures are possible.

Comment: ResNet cannot be implemented as a Sequential model, because the connections are not sequential. You don't need this anyways, just use the Functional API.

Comment: later I finish my problem , I got result test loss :17%, test acc 98%, but my result is very strange I want to train my modelto see single world but it always got the wrong one!!  "M"   ,actuactually is not the english word!!